# Is use of ConfigureAwait(false) correct in this case?

Tags: asynchronous, oauth-2.0, async-await, owin

I have an ASP.NET MVC app and
I have a OAuth Request Resource Owner Password flow for authentication, like this:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(
    OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    var userManager = (CustomUserManager)context.OwinContext.Get<>();
    var user = await userManager 
        .FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password)
        .ConfigureAwait(false)
    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);    
    context.Validated(ticket);
}
```

The problem is this: if i don't have ConfigureAwait(false), i'm geting deadlock and Task was canceled exception.
But with ConfigureAwait(false), everything works fine.

But my question is it correct to use ConfigureAwait(false) in this case?
Is it ok to lose context with ConfigureAwait(false) in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It should only deadlock if something further up the stack is blocking on the asynchronous code. Likely an MVC filter, since those cannot (yet) be async.

It is OK to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` as a workaround, as long as the `AuthenticationTicket` constructor and `AuthenticationTicket.Validated` can run outside the ASP.NET request context. I have no idea whether they can or not.

Note that these kinds of hacks are short-lived at this point; ASP.NET vNext will support asynchronous MVC action filters, and then the code can be fully asynchronous.